# Find the highest N numbers in an infinite list

Tags: java, list, treeset

I was asked this question in a recent Java interview.

> Given a List containing millions of items, maintain a list of the highest n items. Sorting the list in descending order then taking the first n items is definitely not efficient due to the list size.

Below is what I did, I'd appreciate if anyone could provide a more efficient or elegant solution as I believe this could also be solved using a `PriorityQueue`:

```
public TreeSet<Integer> findTopNNumbersInLargeList(final List<Integer> largeNumbersList, 
final int highestValCount) {

    TreeSet<Integer> highestNNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    for (int number : largeNumbersList) {
        if (highestNNumbers.size() < highestValCount) {
            highestNNumbers.add(number);
        } else {
            for (int i : highestNNumbers) {
                if (i < number) {
                    highestNNumbers.remove(i);
                    highestNNumbers.add(number);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return highestNNumbers;
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to implement a simple, bounded, ordered, circular buffer - maybe based on a `TreeSet`. Then simply use that to maintain the top X.

Comment: what if you have duplicate elements?

Comment: first i would ask how the list is contained is it random or what, if it has some particular order to it you can use that to slice the list and what not to fit what they want. for loops nested aren't efficient I think since you may then have `1,000,000^3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need nested loops, just keep inserting and remove the smallest number when the set is too large:

```
public Set<Integer> findTopNNumbersInLargeList(final List<Integer> largeNumbersList, 
  final int highestValCount) {

  TreeSet<Integer> highestNNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();

  for (int number : largeNumbersList) {
    highestNNumbers.add(number);
    if (highestNNumbers.size() > highestValCount) {
      highestNNumbers.pollFirst();
    }
  }
  return highestNNumbers;
}
```

The same code should work with a `PriorityQueue`, too. The runtime should be `O(n log highestValCount)` in any case.

P.S. As pointed out in the other answer, you can optimize this some more (at the cost of readability) by keeping track of the lowest number, avoiding unnecessary inserts.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `pollLast()` instead?

Comment: The default order is ascending, so pollFirst will remove the smallest number, which is what we want here.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, forgot about using the pollFirst() method. No point reinventing code badly.

Answer (score 6):

The `for` loop at the bottom is unnecessary, because you can tell right away if the `number` should be kept or not.

`TreeSet` lets you find the smallest element in `O(log N)`<sup>*</sup>. Compare that smallest element to `number`. If the `number` is greater, add it to the set, and remove the smallest element. Otherwise, keep walking to the next element of `largeNumbersList`.

The worst case is when the original list is sorted in ascending order, because you would have to replace an element in the `TreeSet` at each step. In this case the algorithm would take `O(K log N)`, where `K` is the number of items in the original list, an improvement of log<sub>N</sub>K over the solution of sorting the array.

**Note:** If your list consists of `Integer`s, you could use a linear sorting algorithm that is not based on comparisons to get the overall asymptotic complexity to `O(K)`. This does not mean that the linear solution would be necessarily faster than the original for any fixed number of elements.

<sup>*</sup> You can maintain the value of the smallest element as you go to make it `O(1)`.

Comment: yes this is the best answer I think anyone could give, honestly in this situation I think the person listening to your answer should care more about the logic and algorithm as well as time complexity then the syntax and such.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on your O(1) solution?

Comment: Radix sorting and friends aren't necessary for O(1) per element; see my answer.

Comment: @gsdev The smallest element among top `N` can only go up when you insert a new element into the tree set (an `O(Log N)` operation). If you get the smallest element from the top N at the same time (a second `O(Log N)` operation) you can store the value in a separate variable, so you can get it for `O(1)` on subsequent iterations. Note that this optimization does not change the asymptotic complexity in the worst case, but the improvement could be considerable with some favorable ordering. For example, if the original list is in descending order, the last K-N checks complete in O(1).

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to support amortized O(1) processing of new elements and O(n) querying of the current top elements as follows:

Maintain a buffer of size 2n, and whenever you see a new element, add it to the buffer.  When the buffer gets full, use quick select or another linear median finding algorithm to select the current top n elements, and discard the rest.  This is an O(n) operation, but you only need to perform it every n elements, which balances out to O(1) amortized time.

This is the algorithm Guava uses for [Ordering.leastOf](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java#L648), which extracts the top n elements from an Iterator or Iterable.  It is fast enough in practice to be quite competitive with a PriorityQueue based approach, and it is much more resistant to worst case input.

Comment: There's always _something_ in Guava... Any idea if that made it into Java 8?

Comment: No, Stream.sorted().limit(n) wastefully sorts the whole stream, though that would have been the logical place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by saying that your question, as stated, is impossible. There is no way to find the highest `n` items in a `List` without fully traversing it. And there is no way to fully traverse an infinite `List`.

That said, the text of your question differs from the title. There is a **massive** difference between very large and infinite. Please bear that in mind.

To answer the feasible question, I would begin by implementing a buffer class to encapsulate the behaviour of keeping the top `N`, lets call it `TopNBuffer`:

```
class TopNBuffer<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final NavigableSet<T> backingSet = new TreeSet<>();

    private final int limit;

    public TopNBuffer(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void add(final T t) {
        if (backingSet.add(t) && backingSet.size() > limit) {
            backingSet.pollFirst();
        }
    }

    public SortedSet<T> highest() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet(backingSet);
    }
}
```

All we do here is to, on `add`, if the number is not unique, and adding the number makes the `Set` exceeds its limit, then we simply remove the lowest element from the `Set`.

The method `highest` gives an unmodifiable view of the current highest elements. So, in Java 8 syntax, all you need to do is:

```
final TopNBuffer<Integer> topN = new TopNBuffer<>(n);
largeNumbersList.foreach(topN::add);
final Set<Integer> highestN = topN.highest();
```

I think in an interview environment, its not enough to simply whack lots of code into a method. Demonstrating an understanding of OO programming and separation of concerns is also important.

Comment: Given a List containing millions of items, maintain a list of the highest n items. Sorting the list in descending order then taking the first n items is definitely not efficient due to the list size.

Comment: @Kick That's exactly what this code does. Except it's a `Set` to adding to the highest n is `O(lg n)` rather than `O(n)` as it would be with a `List`. Please read and understand the code before commenting.

Comment: Hi Kick, the question was asked during a Java interview I had. The task is to maintain the top n numbers added to a very large list.

Comment: @gsdev it looks like an awesome question. I am preparing for Google too, but the question is not that clear to me. can you explain better? so what I understood is sort the list without using sorting method? when u remove the smallest number where they go? can u explain in detail plz?

Comment: @Kick, The interviewer asked me to maintain the top n items in a list containing millions of entries. They pointed out that due to the size of the list, sorting the list and then taking the first n items was not a valid answer. They wanted me to solve the problem in the most efficient way.